# Sub queries in Cypher Query Language

Tags: neo4j, subquery

I want to write a CREATE relationship statement for a project i'm working on. The statement has to be something like this

```
CREATE (match (p:Halt) where p.name="Ananda College" return p)-[:next_halt {route:['103'],dist:1.45}]->(MATCH (p:Halt) where p.name="Borella" return p)
```

As you can see i want the start node and end node to have values coming from another CQL statement.
But when i run this query there seems to be a syntax error. I have gone through some tutorials to see where my query is wrong but being a beginner i can't really tell.

```
Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, comment, node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 1, column 15 (offset: 14))
"CREATE (match (p:Halt) where p.name="Ananda College" return p)-[:next_halt {route:['103'],dist:1.45}]->(MATCH (p:Halt) where p.name="Borella" return p)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you found that syntax, but you can find an extensive primer on Cypher [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is rather mixed up here. Please reread the dev documentation and maybe look at the Cypher cheat sheet.

As for proper syntax, you don't even need nesting to get what you want. First, you match on your start and end nodes, then you can use the bound variables in other parts of your query, such as to create a relationship:

```
MATCH (start:Halt), (stop:Halt) 
WHERE start.name = "Ananda College" AND stop.name="Borella"
CREATE (start)-[:next_halt {route:['103'], dist:1.45}]->(stop)
```

If you aren't sure if nodes (or the relationship) exist or not, you can use MERGE instead, which will MATCH on existing nodes (or relationships) or create them if they do not exist.